# CSS height not transitioning in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

help me out here with why my CSS transition isn't working.

I'm trying to animate a height change to a <div> element, either growing it or shrinking it, through a Javascript function. My markup is this:

```
<div class="post series expandcollapse" id="id1" style="height: 32px;">
    <p class="expandcollapse_link" id="expandcollapselink1" name="expandcollapselink1" onclick="toggleCollapsedItem('1');"><img id="expandcollapseimage1" name="expandcollapseimage1" class="expandcollapse" src="images/icons/expandcollapse.png" alt=""></p>
    <h2 onclick="toggleCollapsedItem('1');">Some random heading here</h2>
    <p>Some random text here</p>
</div>
```

The CSS attached to the <div>, <h2>, and <img> are:

```
div.expandcollapse { border-bottom-left-radius: 20px; border-bottom-right-radius: 20px; height: 32px; transition: all 5s ease-in; overflow: hidden; }
div.expandcollapse h2 { cursor: pointer; }
div.expandcollapse img.expandcollapse { transition: all .5s; cursor: pointer; }
div.expandcollapse p.expandcollapse_link { float: right; margin-top: -2px; }
```

When the user clicks on this, it launches this Javascript function:

```
function toggleCollapsedItem(clickedItem, forceOpen = false) {
    var collapsedItem = document.getElementById('id' + clickedItem);
    var collapsedLink = document.getElementById('expandcollapselink' + clickedItem);
    var collapsedImage = document.getElementById('expandcollapseimage' + clickedItem);
    if(typeof collapsedItem.originalHeight === 'undefined') {
        Object.defineProperty(collapsedItem, 'originalHeight', { value: collapsedItem.style.height, writable: false });
    }
    if((collapsedItem.style.height === collapsedItem.originalHeight) || (forceOpen === true)) {
        collapsedItem.style.height = 'auto';
        collapsedImage.style.transform = 'rotate(45deg)';
    } else {
        collapsedItem.style.height = collapsedItem.originalHeight;
        collapsedImage.style.transform = '';
    }
}
```

The image rotates gradually (according to the transition) exactly as it should, but the height doesn't care about the transition. Can anyone spot my problem here? I've been up and down Google, Stackoverflow for similar questions, all over the place, and I can't get the height to change gradually.

Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot transition to or from `auto` values, only between defined values.

I'm assuming the element can be of varying height. If you're already using Javascript, you can transition from `32px` to the element's `offsetHeight`.

So instead

```
collapsedItem.style.height = 'auto';
```

you'd do

```
collapsedItem.style.height = collapsedItem.offsetHeight+'px';
```

Comment: Yes, the element can be of varying height. I tried using offsetHeight, and that sort of did the trick. It does transition now, but it only extends to 36px, not nearly tall enough. (One element, for instance, is 663.25px.) Any idea where it could be coming up with that number?

Comment: Are you using `float` on any elements inside?

Comment: Yes, I am. I have an image with a float right. Does that affect it? Would it be against site policy (like advertising or such) to send a URL?

Comment: Floated elements are not considered when calculating height of the containing element. Google "clearfix" and apply it to the element.